# Rails create custom view and route similar to new.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, nested-routes

I'm looking to create a custom nested view that behaves similar to `new.html.erb` but not exactly sure how to do so with Rails 6.

In my routes I've defined the following -

```
resources :courses do
  resources :courselocations, shallow: true do
    member do
      match :new_modal, via: :all
    end
  end
end
```

My controller is defined as follows -

```
  def new_modal
    @courselocation = Courselocation.new
  end
```

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I click the link `new_modal_admin_course_courselocations_path(@course)` w/ for the custom route, I get the following error which seems to show that rails is not treating this as an action similar to `new`

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Courselocation without an ID):
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I notice that your path tag sends the parameter @course.  Unless I'm mistaken, a new_path doesn't send any parameters.  (I'm a bit of a Rails noob through).

Comment: The courselocations is a nested attribute of courses so a user can create a courselocation associated  with a course.

Comment: Got it.  Then I think you might need something like
new_modal_admin_course_courselocations_path(:course => @course)

Comment: or maybe something like


new_modal_admin_course_courselocations_path(params: {course: @course})